# iOS: How to see recipients of an email or text message

Tags: ios

I'm using `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

After the user sends an email or text. How can I tell who they sent it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Apple intentionally does not disclose this info to the app that presented the interface.